# Arduino Voltage Divider Connection

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Can anyone explain the connection of the voltage divider in this image, why it's connected to A0? 
I put a red circle on the section that i don't understand.
[image: Circuit image]

Answer (score 2):

The voltage divider reduces the battery voltage by a factor of \$\frac{R2}{R2+R3} = \frac{1000}{2500} = 0.40\$. This puts it in a range that allows the Arduino to measure it. 0 to 12.6 V (minus the diode drop) becomes 0 to 4.8 V, which can be measured by the ADC, which accepts 0 to 5 V.

Comment: Is the resistors R2 and R3 considered as the load between the positive and negative terminals of the battery, so no short circuit?!

Comment: Why would there be a short circuit? The current through the resistors will be about \$\frac{12\text{ V}}{2500\Omega} = 4.8\text{ mA}\$.

Comment: Thanks for this clarity. Another question, for what is this diode and how much the voltage drop on it?

Comment: Two things: First, without the diode, the range of the battery voltage would slightly exceed the range of the ADC. And second, it somewhat protects the Arduino from short-term voltage sags caused by the motors, allowing it to run from the energy stored in its Vin capacitors. Adding additional capacitance between Vin and ground would help in this regard.

Comment: This diode is 1N4001 which operate to 1A, means it limits the current?

Comment: No. But the Arduino should never draw anywhere near that much anyway.

Comment: I googled this diode number and found this, "Its blocking voltage varies from 50 volts (1N4001) to 1000 volts (1N4007)". What does it mean to be blocking voltage?

Comment: The blocking voltage is the maximum reverse bias that it can withstand. As long as the value is greater than your battery voltage, the Arduino is protected from accidentally connecting the battery backwards (another function that I should have mentioned).

Comment: That's clear now. And as you recommend adding capacitors between Vin and GND. How can i calculate the capacitors that i need, or should i randomly add small values?

Comment: That's really a separate question. Basically, \$C = \frac{I\cdot\Delta t}{\Delta V}\$, where \$I\$ is the current being drawn by the Arduino, \$\Delta t\$ is the length of time of a typical "sag", and \$\Delta V\$ is the amount of voltage drop the Arduino can tolerate during that time. Obviously, these values depend very much on your specific application, so I can't be more specific.

Comment: But anyway the voltage inside the Arduino is regulated to 5V, so if there is a voltage sag i think it would change nothing. Am i right? And what the Arduino has to do with the motors' voltage, it is directly connected to the ESC and then to the motors. In brief, i mean the Arduino is now isolated from whatever happens with the motors and ESCs.

Comment: Yes, the regulator means that there can be quite a lot of "sag" on Vin before it drops out of regulation. And yes, this "isolation" is one of the functions of the diode (and the regulator).